# Catching errors from callback handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

The perception is that if anything goes wrong within the promise, the catch handler is called but not in the following case when there's a callback involved.

Consider this scenario when an error occurs within a callback function and I assume the scope changes because the callback function is no longer under the PromiseCatcher's call stack and someone else is calling your callback. (Hope someone can correctly word this technically).

```
function query(sql, fn) { 
    setTimeout(fn, 1000);
}

function getUsers() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        query("SELECT * FROM user", function(){ // callback crashes
            console.log(b); // undefined var, crash + stack trace
        });
    });
}

getUsers().then(console.log, function(e){
    console.log("caught in catch", e); // objective is to catch all errors here
})
```

**Attempt 01** Fail

I am using a try-catch within promise:

```
function getUsers() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            query("SELECT * FROM user", function(){
                console.log(b); // undefined variable
            });
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("trying to catch error but no success", e)
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

**Attempt 02** Success

I placed a try-catch within the callback method:

```
function getUsers() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        query("SELECT * FROM user", function(){
            try {
                console.log(b); // undefined variable
            } catch(e) {
                console.log("caught finally")
                reject(e); // have to manually reject it.
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Just wondering if someone can give a better suggestion, it's a bit of a nuisance to define try catch within every callback method nested within promises I've.

My objective is to receive all errors in my `catch` handler.

### Response to proposed duplicate

I don't think this question is a duplicate [of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712602/catching-all-promise-rejections-in-an-async-function-in-javascript) - I believe it is a totally different situation. (The linked answer talks about catching all rejections, whereas in this question I've an error occurring deeper inside a callback that fails to report).

My question deals with a scenario with a nested function inside a promise that has a callback. That callback is simply rogue.

Put simply, nested callback function to a function inside a promise fails to report and any error crashes the program with a stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching All Promise Rejections in an Async Function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712602/catching-all-promise-rejections-in-an-async-function-in-javascript)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, you've to dig deeper to understand, added some more comments. See edit please.

Comment: do i really have to define `try/catch` within every callback?

Comment: In my opinion it's not a good idea, when you `return` the `Promise` wheter `rejected` or `fulfilled` you should be able to catch the error within the `catch` method from `Promises`. I'll post an answer to explain better what I meant I understand it's a little vague.

Comment: yes in theory but it's not happening. Please run the first piece of code and see for yourself. Then replace `getUsers` with the version of attempt 02 and see the difference.

Comment: I will, I'll be in touch soon.

Comment: can you remove the duplicate tag please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193936/discussion-between-sigfried-and-developer).